# lines not showing up on line graph in R when using plot() then lines()

Tags: r, graph, line

I'm trying to create a line graph using data from different columns in the same data frame.  I can create the initial plot but when I go to add `lines()`, nothing shows up.

I've tried creating individual vectors for the data in the columns and using `lines()` with instead of pulling it out of the data frame, but that doesn't work, neither does extracting it directly from the data frame.

```
plot(re_date, date_sub$Sub_metering_1, type = "l", xlab = "", ylab = "Energy sub metering")
lines(date_sub$Sub_metering_2, col = "red")
lines(date_sub$Sub_metering_3, col = "blue")
```

(note: the x variable, `re_date` is a separate vector I've created after converting the date/time column in the original `date_sub` data frame.
That shouldn't have any effect on the y variable?

the initial plot works well, but then no new red or blue lines.  When I use the same data for the lines in plot() replacing `date_sub$Sub_metering_1` with `date_sub$Sub_metering_2` (and `_3` respectively) they both create line graphs. 
I thought maybe it was because the information was on the y-axis, so I even tried 
`lines( ,date_sub$Sub_metering_2, col = "red")`.

I realize lines() is missing type = "l" as well.  I was running it with the "l", then came across one instructional site that had ommitted it, and thought, oh, well it IS somewhat redundant, so I took it out, and still, same result.

I am new to R and apologize if this is a foolish question.

Comment: It's hard to say much without a reproducible example, but my guess would be that the scale of your original graph is off for red and blue lines. Consider increasing the x/y axis using `xlim` and `ylim`.

Comment: Consider using `matplot`.

Answer (score 3):

In your `plot` statement you have a x and y component (re_date, date_sub$Sub_metering_1).

When you call `lines` you only provide y. R does not know that you also want 
`re_date` as x-axis. You have to tell R explicitly because otherwise the x values of the data you want to plot with `lines` is simply `x=1:length(date_sub$Sub_metering_2)`, i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4,5 ...

Try the following:

```
plot(re_date, date_sub$Sub_metering_1, type = "l", xlab = "", ylab = "Energy sub metering")
lines(re_date, date_sub$Sub_metering_2, col = "red")
lines(re_date, date_sub$Sub_metering_3, col = "blue")
```

Comment: thank you SO MUCH @PhillipD! it worked, that's all it needed.  I knew it was something fairly simple I was not doing!